# POST http://localhost:3000/api/users/login 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, api, express, server, routes

So I have a login form that currently looks like that :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { Form, Button, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./LoginScreen.css";
import axios from 'axios';



  function LoginScreen() {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const submitHandler = async (e) => { 
      e.preventDefault();
      
      try {
        const config = {
          headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json",
          },
        }

        setLoading(true)

        const { data } = await axios.post(
          '/api/users/login',
          {
          email, password,
          },
          config);
        console.log(data);
        localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(data));
        setLoading(false);

      } catch (error) {
        setError(error.response.data.message);
        }
    }

      return (   
          <div className="login_outer">
              <h1>Login Here</h1>
       <div className="loginContainer">
            <Form onSubmit={ submitHandler }>
           <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail" >
             <Form.Label>E-mail: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control size="lg" type="email" value={email} placeholder="Enter Email" className="input" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
           </Form.Group>
           <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
             <Form.Label>Password: </Form.Label>
                <Form.Control size="lg" type="password" value={password} placeholder="Enter Password" className="input" onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
           </Form.Group>
           <Button  className="login_button" variant="primary" type="submit">
             Submit
           </Button>
         </Form>
         <Row className="py-3">
           <Col>
             New User ? <Link to="/register">Register Here</Link>
           </Col>
         </Row>
       </div>
    </div>
   );
 }

 export default LoginScreen;
```

When I click the submit button I get the error:
POST http://localhost:3000/api/users/login 404 (Not Found)
In my server.js I have:

```
const userRoutes = require('./routes/userRoutes.js');

const dotenv = require('dotenv');

const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const { notFound, errorHandler } = require('./middlewares/errorMiddleware');

dotenv.config();
connectDB();
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("API is running..");
});

app.use('/api/users', userRoutes);

app.use(notFound);
app.use(errorHandler);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server started on PORT ${PORT}`));
```

and in my routes I have:

```
const express = require('express');
const { registerUser, authUser } = require('../controllers/userControllers');

const router = express.Router();


router.route('/').post(registerUser);
router.post("/login", authUser);

module.exports = router;
```

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it ? I think it is something to do with the server file.

UPDATE!: I have fixed the error by getting a proxy, but now I when I try to login I get 401 unauthorized. Anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: Are any of your other endpoints working?

Comment: /users is working but /login is not found

Comment: I'm not seeing where your axios.baseUrl is configured, but your error is on port 3000 and server defaults to port 5000 when no process.env.PORT is supplied. Can you confirm that those ports match?

Comment: I am using a proxy for localhost3000 so it sends requests to PORT 5000

Comment: Probably don't have enough details to answer your updated question. It probably has something to do with your login/auth middleware

Answer (score 0):

Delete "proxy": "http://localhost:3000". Install package `http-proxy-middleware` with command:

```
npm install http-proxy-middleware --save
```

Create a file `setupProxy.js` inside your src folder or the root of your folder. Add these lines inside:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:5000',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```